# Turn recovery on after first message

Tags: performance, scala, akka, akka-persistence

I have a persistent actor which receives many messages. Fist message is CREATE (case class) and next messages are UPDATEs (case classes). So if it receives CREATE then it should not go into persistence to run recovery because the storage is empty for this actor. It's performance wasting from my perspective.

Is there any possibility to do not call recovery for particular input message (the first one which is CREATE), please?

Comment: What is the performance impact of recovery? How often does it happen? How long does it take? Why is it a waste? You have stated a number of opinions but provided no facts.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question. Do you have actors that extends `akka.persistence.PersistentActor` which receives some CREATE and UPDATE messages ?

Comment: **What is the performance impact of recovery?**
It's quite fast operation (the one recovery)
**How often does it happen?**
It occurs 1K - 3K times per second.
**Why is it a waste?**
I do not want query storage If I know the storage is empty for the CREATE message. The query is needless and therefore it's a waste.

Comment: **I am not sure to understand your question. Do you have actors that extends akka.persistence.PersistentActor which receives some CREATE and UPDATE messages ?**
Yes. I have.

Comment: Thank you for replies. Much appreciate.

Comment: Maybe i am wrong, but what as my understand of akka-persistence is to persist the state of the actors and to recover that state by replaying the messages it received. So if akka doesn't persist the CREATE message how it could know that the CREATE message was arrived and thus recreate the correct actor's state ?

Comment: **So if akka doesn't persist the CREATE message how it could know that the CREATE message was arrived and thus recreate the correct actor's state ?** I want persist all messages but I don't want query (recovery) persistence for first message because I know that the query returns empty result for every first message (CREATE).

Answer (score 0):

A persistent actor will always have to hit the database, because there is no other way to know whether it having existed before - it could have been created in a previous instance of the application that was stopped or it could have been created on a different node in a cluster.

In general a good pattern for performance is to keep the actor in memory after it has been hit the first time, as that will allow as fast responses as possible. The most common way to do this is using Cluster Sharding (which you can read more about in the docs here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-sharding.html?language=scala#cluster-sharding

I have never heard of anyone seeing the hit for an empty persistent actor as a performance problem and I'm not sure it is possible to solve that in a general way, so if you have such a problem and somehow can know the actor was never created before you can not do that with Akka Persistence but would have to build a special solution for that yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I use sharding and I have it in memory. And it is empty form the particular actor perspective (for example actor with persistence ID equal to 123 has nothing in the storage for the first message).

Comment: My project is BigData and I am trying to save every millisecond. What is more this is quite reasonable from my perspective. Imagine that you have 1TB persistent storage and around 3K new actors per second for which you know that storage is empty (no result is returned from storage's first query - for my first CREATE message) then it's time wasting to ask the storage for the first time for the fist actor's message. Anyway much appreciate.